# CouchDB: Get unique values

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have a database where I need to fetch some values. The database consists of documents containing rooms, each room with the property "floor" and "hotel" (and a couple more, but they are not important here).

The thing is; I need to get all the floors at the hotel I ask for. `getAllFloorsOnHotel("hotel")` kinda thing. But I don't know how to query the database. I've read here: http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/cookbook.html#unique, but it is not quite what I need. There they use the key together with `group=true` to remove duplicates, and this would work if the floor was the key, but in my case the hotel is the key. Therefore, if I use `group=true` I naturally only get 1 floor at that hotel back. If I don't use `group=true`, I get all the floors on the specified hotel back - with duplicates.

How can I make couchdb give me all the floors of a hotel back, without duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an array for the key.

In your map function, your emit should look something like this:

```
emit([doc.hotel, doc.floor], null);
```

I've put null for the value, but it can be anything you want to use for your reduce function. To get a list of every floor at every hotel your reduce function can just return true.

Then when you query, use group_level instead of group and assign it to the level of the array you would like it grouped by. group_level=2 will group by floor.

To query with curl for rooms you'd go:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5894/yourDB/yourView?group_level=2
```

This will give you all the hotels, with all their floors. To get the list of a particular hotel you need to query a range. It's difficult to show how to do this with curl, as you have to do all sorts of stuff to the array string to get it to work. The variables you need are startkey and endkey. You're probably using ajax anyway, so just pass these as options.

```
startkey: ["hotelName", 0],
endkey: ["hotelName", {}],
group_level: 2
```

The 0 and the {} are just low and high values. {} is sorted last, so whatever your string is will be between those two things.

Also, if you use descending: true, you'll need to switch the 0 and {} around. (That caused me a lot of pain)

There's some more info here:
[CouchDB sorting and filtering in the same view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311225/couchdb-sorting-and-filtering-in-the-same-view/3313336#3313336)

Comment: Thank you, it works! And I understood it as well ;) Oh, and I'm not using AJAX, I'm using Objective-C. Anyway, if anyone needs it, look here for more info as well: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html#comments